# Как ограничить ввод между значениями 0.2 и 2 (В регулярном выражении)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, валидация

- Как ограничить ввод между значениями **не меньше 0.2 и не больше 2**

Как написать регулярку такую /

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit

import sys

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.le_input = QLineEdit(self)

        # reg_ex = QRegExp("[0-9]{2,1}+.?[0-9]{,1}")

        reg_ex = QRegExp("^([0-2]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$")   # регулярка на вводимые значения
        input_validator = QRegExpValidator(reg_ex, self.le_input)
        self.le_input.setValidator(input_validator)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()

    a.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:0[,.][2-9]|1(?:[,.][0-9])?|2(?:[,.]0)?)$
```

`^` - начало строки
`(?:...)` - незахватываемая группа
`0[,.][2-9]` - цифра 0 после которой идет один из разделителей и цифра в диапазоне от 2 до 9
`|` - логическое или
`1(?:[,.][0-9])?` - цифра 1 после которой в группе описан разделитель точка или запятая и любая цифра, на группу установлен квантификатор, что делает ее необязательной
`|2(?:[,.]0)?` - или 2 c необязательным написание разделителя и ноля
`$` - конец строки

Пример на js:

```js
const reg = /^(?:0[,.][2-9]|1(?:[,.][0-9])?|2(?:[,.]0)?)$/gm;
const str = `
0,1
0,2
1,3
2
2.1
2.0
1
,,2
02`;

console.log(str.match(reg));
```

Answer (score 0):

Подобрал сам ))

```
reg_ex = QRegExp("^([1][.|,][0-9]|[0|,|.][,|.][2-9]|[1]|[2]$)")
```

Comment: 0.21 не проходит, это нормально?

Comment: да, после точки может быть тока одно число. Одно тока не могу найти как ввести чисто единицу в свое выражение... Вместо 1.0 вводить 1

Comment: Вообще в документации рекомендуют "Чтобы получить контроль диапазона (например, для IP-адреса), используйте маски вместе с `validators`." https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop

Comment: а мне кажется регулярки более гибкие возможности дают (у меня своя хотелка чисто )) )

Comment: в принципе у меня всe, регулярка готова ))

Comment: `1|9` - это число такой. Ваша регулярка его пропускает.

Comment: число 1 вводится норм, 1.9 тоже, 19 не вводиться, 9 не вводится... Не думаю что пользователь будет вводить 1|9 с символом | ... А так не знаю как исключить данный символ, спасибо что заметили )

Comment: Это chatGPT такой reg написал?

Comment: `,.9` тоже пропускает.

Comment: `^(?!0\.1)[01]\.\d$`